# почему $socket.Available не работает а $stream.DataAvailable работает?

Tags: windows, powershell

Пишу проект на powershell & python, возникла проблема.
Ранее использовал stream и tcpClient при работе, но теперь использую socket по техническим проблемам. Ранее при работе использовал `$stream.DataAvailable` для проверки есть ли данные в буфере. Однако сейчас я попробовал провернуть то же с сокетом: `$socket.Available -gt 0`, но условие всегда ложно.

на серверной части всё верно, ведь когда был stream всё работало исправно. Есть ли догадки? вот полный код на данный момент с сокетом:

```
$server_port = 1336;
$server_ip = '127.0.0.1';

$socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket(
    [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork,
    [System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream,
    [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp
);

while ($socket.Available -gt 0) {
      Write("Packet Received");
      $packet_length = New-Object byte[] 1;
      $len = $socket.Receive($packet_length);
      $packet = New-Object byte[] $packet_length[0];
      $len = $socket.Receive($packet);
}
```

Вот код с $stream.DataAvailable:

```
$port = 1336;
$server_ip = '127.0.0.1';

$ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server_ip) | Where-Object 
{$PSItem.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'};
$socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient($ip, $port);
$stream = $socket.GetStream();
while ($stream.DataAvailable) {
      Write("Packet Received");
      $packet_length = New-Object byte[] 1;
      $len = $stream.Read($packet_length, 0, $packet_length.Length);
      $packet = New-Object byte[] $packet_length[0];
      $len = $stream.Read($packet, 0, $packet.Length);
}
```

Comment: Покажите код с DataAvailable для сравнения? (Не очень представляю, как он вообще мог работать...)

Comment: @andreymal добавил

Comment: Всё равно не очень понимаю, как оно может работать... Нет никакой гарантии, что отправитель успеет прислать данные до проверки Available или DataAvailable

Comment: @andreymal
это лишь кусок моего кода, так всё загнано в цикл while ($true)
весь код выслать если даже получиться, то наврядли что-то будет понятно